# How can I make Validate-set also to work for mandatory parameter input prompt?

Tags: powershell

I use dynamic validate sets for my functions for mandatory parameters.

When not provided Powershell prompts and forces user to input.

However in this case, TAB does not respond and I have to type the value.

Is there a way to make dynamic validate set to be available on the prompt?

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt it is.

Comment: I dont think that there is a way to do that because it is more like a backend PS engine job. But if there is a way , I would love to know that very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## There's nothing *you* can do!

The reason is that the prompt presented to you by the host application does not have the necessary information available to cycle through valid values.

To understand why, it's essential to understand exactly what happens when you invoke a cmdlet without passing an argument to a `Mandatory` parameter. Let's explore!

First, let's define a simple sample function:

```
function Test-ValidateSet {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateSet('a','b','c')]
    [string[]]$Character
  )

  Write-Host "You entered: $Character!"
}
```

If you want to see what PowerShell ***does*** to a statement when you hit enter, use `Trace-Command`.

```
PS C:\> Trace-Command ParameterBinding {Test-ValidateSet} -PSHost
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Test-ValidateSet]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Test-ValidateSet]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Test-ValidateSet]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PROMPTING for missing mandatory parameters using the host
cmdlet Test-ValidateSet at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Character[0]:
```

These `DEBUG` messages must have been emitted from where the prompt is being called. Searching through the `PowerShell` GitHub repo for "PROMPTING for missing mandatory parameters using the host" will lead you [to this call site](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/CmdletParameterBinderController.cs#L3094).

As you may be able to decipher, the [`Prompt()` method](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/hostifaces/InternalHostUserInterface.cs#L822) takes just 3 things:

1. A caption (`[string]`)
2. A message (`[string]`)
3. A set of descriptions (`[System.Management.Automation.Host.FieldDescription[]]`)

Looking at the properties of a [`FieldDescription`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.fielddescription(v=vs.85).aspx) object, you'll find that they roughly correspond to the `[Parameter]` attribute - no other kind of attribute - and that's basically why you can't tab complete the values based on validation attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use tab on ValidateSet
You can see same behavior if you use Show-Command 
The only pre run validation is ValidateSet

try this:

```
Function Test-Function
{
    Param
    (
        [String]$NormalParameter,
        [ValidateSet('T1','T2','T3')]
        [String]$ValidateSetParameter,
        [ValidatePattern("[T4]|[T5]|[T6]")]
        [String]$ValidatePatternParameter,
        [ValidateScript({$_ -In ('T7','T8','T9')})]
        [String]$ValidateScriptParameter,
        [ValidateRange('A','C')]
        [String]$ValidateRangeParameter
    )   
}

Show-Command Test-Function
```